# Publish Storybook components to NPM using Semantic Release and Github Actions

Tags: github-actions, storybook, semantic-release

[Article for reference](https://dev.to/amalv/publish-storybook-components-to-npm-using-semantic-release-and-github-actions-6ie)

I can set up Github Actions but get stuck on GitHub Release; it says

> Run npx semantic-release [semantic-release]: node version >=16 ||
> ^14.17 is required. Found v12.22.12.
>
> See
> https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/support/node-version.md
> for more details and solutions. Error: Process completed with exit
> code 1.

It says I'm using an older version of Node. However, it's not possible. Both my package.json and node -v says it is 16.x.x.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My working step is:

```
build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ secrets.ADMIN_TOKEN }}

      - name: setup nodejs
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16'

      - name: release using semantic-release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ADMIN_TOKEN }}
          GIT_AUTHOR_NAME: secrets.automation.dev
          GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL: secrets.automation.dev@il.ibm.com
          GIT_COMMITTER_NAME: secrets.automation.dev
          GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL: secrets.automation.dev@il.ibm.com
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install python
          pip install --user bumpversion
          npm install @semantic-release/changelog
          npm install @semantic-release/exec
          npm install @semantic-release/git
          npm install @semantic-release/github
          npx semantic-release
```

the `.releaserc` file is:

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "branches": [ "main" ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@semantic-release/commit-analyzer", {
        "preset": "angular",
        "releaseRules": [
            {"type": "release","release": "patch"}
    ]}],
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    "@semantic-release/changelog",
    [
      "@semantic-release/exec",
      {
        "prepareCmd": "bump2version --allow-dirty --current-version ${lastRelease.version} --new-version ${nextRelease.version} patch"
      }
    ],
    [
      "@semantic-release/git",
      {
        "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} release notes\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
      }
    ],
    "@semantic-release/github"
  ]
}
```